# "Collecting problem information" doesn't end. Apporting does't stop

Tags: libreoffice, 18.10, bug-reporting, apport

I used **ubuntu-bug -w** to send a bug report. About **LibreOffice 6.2.0.3** not having 100% Fullscreen in **Ubuntu 18.10** *(Sometimes it does have Fullscreen)*.

[image: ScreenShot]

It's been like an hour and so-called "Apporting" hasn't stopped.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have installed LibreOffice as Snap.

As far I know, it is impossible to use apport as bug-reporting tool for such applications.

You may try to visit https://snapcraft.io/libreoffice and send error report from this page by clicking on [*Contact Canonical link*](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bugs?field.tag=snap).

---

Note: if you do not like LibreOffice Snap, then you can remove it

```
snap remove libreoffice
```

and install LibreOffice 6.1.5 from their PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```